# filter for custom column in grid view which is not in table yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, kartik-v

I have added this 'sla_status' field in gridview and every thing is working fine only issue is I am unable to set filter values for this.
'sla_status' is not in my table.

```
[
            'label' => Yii::t('app','Sla Status'),
            'format' => 'raw',
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filter' => $status,
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [ 
                    'options' => [ 
                            'placeholder' => Yii::t('app','All...' )
                    ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [ 
                            'allowClear' => true 
                    ] 
            ],

            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align:center;color:#337ab7'],
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget)
            {           }   
            ]
```

and $status is `$status = array('0'=>Yii::t('app', 'Inactive'),'1'=>Yii::t('app', 'Active'));`

Comment: If its in a related table then you need to add this table with relation and then filter it using that

Comment: no it is not any table, I am computing the values for 'sla status' based on the due dates for the task's.So this field actually doesn't exist anywhere in the db itself.

Comment: I think the filter will be based on dates nor based on the status... 
the second thought is that
you need to compare the results and use afterFind event to filter the data or use internalFind

Answer (score 2):

Add a public variable $sla_status and add sla_status as safe in the rules array in search model

```
public $sla_status;
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['sla_status'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Search model you should add attribute sla_status
and in search() add required where.
for example:

```
class TaskSearch extends Task{
public $sla_status;
public function search($params){ 
    $query = Task::find();
    if($this->sla_status){ $query->andWhere(...); } 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your field "sla_status" to "safe" in rules method of your model or search model like

`[['sla_status'], 'safe'],`